# Weird behavior with C's file IO

Tags: c, file-io, undefined-behavior

I've been writing a virtual machine, and I've noticed some strange things have happened, even though I wrote this function ages ago. Anyhow, my virtual machine reads a file like this:

```
0002 000A 0001 0004 0000
```

However, when I **don't** have any whitespace after the 0000 or a new line... it crashes. Another really weird thing, which leads me to believe it's **not** the file loading, is that when you remove the `0000` from the file, and the whitespace... it works?! I've tried running it through GDB, but it actually works -- apparently this is called a heisenbug or something. I think it's due to the way files are loaded, which you can see in [this function here on github](https://github.com/freefouran/toy-lang/blob/master/src/vm.c#L65), or just read the snippet below.

```
void load_program(vm *self) {
    FILE *file = fopen("testing.ayy", "r");

    if (file != NULL) {
        if (fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END) == 0) {
            long file_size = ftell(file);
            if (file_size == -1) {
                perror("could not read filesize\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            self->source = malloc(sizeof(char) * file_size);

            if (fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET) != 0) {
                perror("could not reset file index\n");
                exit(1);
            }

            size_t file_length = fread(self->source, sizeof(char), file_size, file);
            if (file_length == 0) {
                perror("given file is empty\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            self->source[file_size] = '\0';
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
    else {
        perror("could not read file: \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    self->source_compact = strdup(self->source);
    self->source_compact = deblank(self->source_compact);

    // here we divide because strlen is in characters,
    // whereas each instruction code should be 4 characters
    // so we're converting char size to num of instructions
    self->instructions_size = strlen(self->source_compact) / INSTRUCTION_LENGTH;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < self->instructions_size; i++) {
        char *instr = substring(self->source_compact, i);

        if (strcmp(instr, ERROR_CODE)) { // not equal to NOPE
            if (self->instructions != NULL) {
                self->instructions = add_instructions(self->instructions, strtol(instr, NULL, 16));
            }
            else {
                self->instructions = create_instructions(strtol(instr, NULL, 16));
            }
        }
    }

    self->instructions = reverse(self->instructions);
}
```

But I've added a GitHub link, since I'm not sure if it's that function; or if it's due to anything happening in the entire source -- so if any C gurus can help me, that would be brilliant :). I'm certain it's in either `vm.c`, or `vm.h`, and sorry for the terrible code; I never really looked to much into File IO when I was learning (big mistake).

Comment: `self->source[file_size] = '\0';` out of range access.

Comment: Should it be `file_size - 1`, or when I malloc should I do (file_size + 1)?

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(char) * (file_size+1));
`

Comment: this line: self->source = malloc(sizeof(char) * file_size); could fail for several reasons, therefore the returned pointer should be checked to assure validity, before using that pointer.  reasons include: 1) a simple malloc failure 2) the file size is larger than the available heap memory.

Comment: this line: perror("could not read file: \n"); should be: perror("fopen");  The perror writes to stderr, and outputs the message obtained from the strerror() function.

Comment: this line: file_length = fread(self->source, sizeof(char), file_size, file); fread() can return a value less that the third parameter, when a I/O error occurs or EOF occurs, so if (file_length != file_size) { perror("fread:); exit(1); }  I suspect this will make the read problem visible.

Comment: this line: self->source_compact = strdup(self->source); results in a malloc'd memory allocation that (eventually) must be free'd before exiting the program.

Comment: this line: self->source_compact = deblank(self->source_compact); uses the function deblank(), which is very suspect (and not available here for examination.  The next suspect is the definition of "ERROR_CODE".  Could you post the source for deblank() thanks

Comment: Woah, thanks for all the comments. Slowly working my way through them, heres the source for deblank() -- the name is a bit of a misnomer: https://github.com/freefouran/toy-lang/blob/master/vm/src/vm.c#L306

Comment: ERROR_CODE is literally just a string "NOPE", because I cheated a little when I cut up the instructions, so an invalid instruction returns "NOPE".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> self->source = malloc(sizeof(char) * file_size);
> ...
> self->source[file_size] = '\0';
> ```

You need to allocate one more byte for the terminating zero. The index `source[file_size]` is actually one byte beyond the end of the allocated memory. Writing into that location may clobber some other variable or the internal structures used by `malloc()`. Make it:

```
self->source = malloc(sizeof(char) * (file_size + 1));
```

or just:

```
self->source = malloc(file_size + 1);
```

`sizeof(char)` is always `1`, so it is redundant.

If you want to guard yourself in case the type of `self->source` changes, you can use:

```
self->source = malloc ((file_size+1) * sizeof *self->source);
```

which automatically allocates the correct size.

You should also check if the allocation was successful before trying to access the memory.

Comment: Perfect, I just keep the sizeof(char) since people say to do that for portability or what not.

Comment: using sizeof *self->source (which means the size of what ever self-> source is point toward (at this moment in the code, that is undefined) and if sizeof *self->source is greater than 1, then the amount of memory allocation will expand by 2 or 3 or what ever times what the sizeof expresssion returns.  Probably a very bad idea to add that sizeof expression to the malloc parameter

Comment: @user3629249: The `sizeof` operator only cares about the **type** of its argument, and the type has to be known at the point of assignment. The size of the allocation _has to_ be a multiple of size of the type that you are allocating memory for.